# How to use input parameters of stored procedure in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

This is a procedure with some input parameters. Now, I need to use these input parameters in a dynamic sql query but it gives error:

> Invalid column name 'MiddleNameFromTable'.

and same for all the rest of them.

I understand dynamic SQL queries create their own session and can not use declarations made somewhere else but there must be some alternatives?

```
 CREATE Procedure OutputProcedure
 ( 
     @LastNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @LastNameFromTable nvarchar(20), 
     @MiddleNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @MiddleNameFromTable nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @CityFromUser nvarchar(20) = null,
     @CityFromTable nvarchar(20) = null,
    @Percentage int out
)
AS
BEGIN
    select @LastNameFromTable as 'LASTNAMEFROMTABLE'
    select @LastNameFromUser as 'LASTNAMEFROMUser'
    select 'OUTPUTPROCEDURECALLED'

    declare @maxvalue int

    DECLARE @variableTable TABLE (
       idx int identity(1,1),
       matchvalue nvarchar(15)
    )

    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('MiddleName')
    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('LastName')
    INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('City')

    SELECT * FROM @variableTable 

    DECLARE @counter int
    declare @sql nvarchar(100)
    declare @sql2 nvarchar(25), @finalResult nvarchar(100)
    declare @sql3 nvarchar(300), @sql4 nvarchar(15),  @tempresultStore nvarchar(20), @temp int, @temp2 int, @average int

    SET @counter = 1
    SELECT @maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @variableTable)

select @maxvalue as 'MAXVALUE'
WHILE(@counter < @maxvalue)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @colVar nvarchar(15)

    SELECT @colVar = matchvalue FROM @variableTable WHERE idx = @counter
    /*set @sql = 'declare ' + '@Temp'+ @colVar + ' int'
    exec(@sql)
    select @sql as 'SQLFORDECLARATIONS'*/

    /*set @temp = CHARINDEX(' ',@sql)
    select @temp as 'resultofcharindex'
    set @temp2 = LEN(@sql) - (@temp)
    SELECT @temp2 AS 'AFTERADDING1'
    set @tempresultStore = right(@sql, @temp2)*/
    set @tempresultStore = 'Temp'+@colVar
    SELECT @tempresultStore AS 'FINALCUTPART'

set @sql3 = 'declare @Temp' + @colVar + ' int = dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser,' + @colVar + 'FromTable, 0)' 
EXEC(@sql3)  
select @sql3 as 'check sql query formed'

set @finalResult = @finalResult + @tempresultStore
select @finalResult as 'SUM'
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
    select @counter as 'COUNTERVALUE'
    END
    set @Percentage = @finalResult/@maxvalue
    SELECT @Percentage AS 'FINALRESULT'
RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with this procedure. The error you are getting is because of statement generated. Look

```
declare @TempMiddleName int = dbo.[MatchMiddleName](MiddleNameFromUser,MiddleNameFromTable, 0)
```

I suppose you want this

```
declare @TempMiddleName int = dbo.[MatchMiddleName](@MiddleNameFromUser,@MiddleNameFromTable, 0)
```

First change

```
set @sql3 = 'declare @Temp' + @colVar + ' int = dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser,' + @colVar + 'FromTable, 0)'
```

to

```
set @sql3 = 'declare @Temp' + @colVar + ' int = dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](@' + @colVar + 'FromUser,@' + @colVar + 'FromTable, 0)'
```

But it is not enough. You must provide parameters to dynamic query like this:

Add at the top of procedure

```
DECLARE @ParamDefs NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'@MiddleNameFromUser NVARCHAR(20), @MiddleNameFromTable NVARCHAR(20)'
```

and change

```
EXEC(@sql3)
```

to

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql3, @ParamDefs, @MiddleNameFromUser, @MiddleNameFromTable
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Put your:

```
select @sql3 as 'check sql query formed'
```

before your EXEC and see what it is actually constructing then it may be obvious to you.

Comment: What it is constructing is just fine. It has to do with scope of Dynamic SQL query. I am using input parameters of the procedure in the query  which it probably can not see.

Comment: What I suggest is create yourself a table variable, then use something like
INSERT @Table
EXEC(@sql3)

Then you have the results in a table outside of your dynamic sql and you can manipulate it.